# How to use a WooCommerce shortcode as PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

How can use this WooCommerce shortcode in PHP:

```
[products columns="3" attribute="ir" terms="20" orderby="date"]
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 3):

Inside any PHP code, use dedicated WordPress function [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) as follow:

```
echo do_shortcode("[products columns='3' attribute='ir' terms='20' orderby='date']");
```

or inserting that on the html code from a php file:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[products columns='3' attribute='ir' terms='20' orderby='date']"); ?>
```

It will work on your php code.

Comment: That works on all themes, so you are not using it properly… Have you tried: `<?php echo do_shortcode("[products columns='3' attribute='ir' terms='20' orderby='date']"); ?>`.